# Why does my settings form redirect to the homepage?

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'm struggling to figure out why my plugin's settings form is redirecting to the homepage. What I expect is, the settings page should reload after the form is submitted.

Should the form redirect to the homepage? Why is this form directing to the homepage? What am I doing wrong? (I expect I've missed something obvious.)

```
class BlogPlugin {
    public static function run() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( __CLASS__, 'add_menu' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( __CLASS__, 'register_settings' ) );
    }

    public static function add_menu() {
        add_options_page( 'Blog Plugin Settings', 'Blog Plugin', 'edit_pages', 'blog_plugin_settings', array( __CLASS__, 'render_settings_page' ), false, 62 );
    }

    public static function register_settings() {
        register_setting( 'bp_blog_plugin', 'bp_input' );
    }

    public static function render_settings_page() {

        add_settings_section(
            'blog_plugin_settings_section',
            '',
            '',
            'blog_plugin_settings'
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'bp_input',
            'An input',
            array( __CLASS__ , 'input_view' ),
            'blog_plugin_settings',
            'blog_plugin_settings_section'         
        );

        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Blog Plugin Settings</h1>
            <form action="post" action="options.php">
                <?php 
                    settings_fields( 'bp_blog_plugin' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'blog_plugin_settings' );
                    submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    public static function input_view(){
        echo('<input type="text" name="bp_input">');
    }
}

BlogPlugin::run();
```

**Edit**

I have removed the reference to the non-existent function and have confirmed that the plugin runs on my installation. (The form still redirects to the homepage.)

Comment: There are several references to non-existing functions in your code, so we can not test it. Could you post a sample code that we can use to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Having had a good night's sleep, I see the typo is glaringly obvious.

I have:

```
<form action="post" action="options.php">
```

It should be:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
```